# Why does reading int in little endian form give me the correct result without modification?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the header of a WAV file, and according to this specification, the second 4-byte chunk is the size of the whole file minus 8 bytes, and it is written in little endian form.

[image]

Which means that if I try to read the second 4-bytes then I must re-arrange them in order to get the correct number.

However, when using this code, I found that it prints the correct number without having to re-arrange it.

```
std::ifstream file(p, std::ios::binary);

// RIFF header
char riff[5]{}; riff[4] = '\0'; // null terminator for cout
// size of the file minus 8 bytes
int size_of_file;
// wave 
char wave[5]{}; wave[4] = '\0';

file.read(riff, 4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size_of_file), 4);
file.read(wave, 4);

std::cout << riff << std::endl; // prints RIFF
std::cout << size_of_file << std::endl; // prints the correct number (how?)
std::cout << wave << std::endl; // prints WAVE
```

How does that happen? Why didn't I have to re-arrange the bytes?

Comment: You ran this code on a little-endian machine, right?

Comment: You didn't specify your platform, but desktop computers (aka x86) are little-endian.

Comment: I ran it on a little-endian machine but how does that make the output different?

Comment: Little-endian machines load little-endian data correctly. That's what makes them little-endian machines, little-endian is their native format.

Comment: When your CPU's native word-format is little-endian, the conversion from little-endian format to CPU-native format is a no-op, so you can get away without performing it.  If you run the program on a bit-endian CPU (e.g. a PowerPC), OTOH, you'll get the wrong value unless you convert the little-endian data to big-endian/CPU-native before trying to use it.

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).

Comment: Ahh I get it now, thank you both.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank you for the read, I get it now.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner but why did reading the RIFF header and the WAVE header also work even though they were in big-endian?

Comment: Because you’re treating them as char arrays, which are handled the same on all modern machines.  If you had read them into uint32_t’s instead of into char[4] and printed out the values of the uint32_t’s afterwards, that would give you different results on a little-endian vs big-endian cpu.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Please bear with me because I have a hard time understanding this, but when my code reaches the first `file.read(riff, 4)` line it tells the os 'give me the first 4 bytes' so the os responds by giving it the first four bytes but this time reversed (since it is little endian) shouldn't the array then be {F, F, I, R}?

Comment: You are using bad (confusing) documentation. Take a look at your WAV file in a hex editor - the `RIFF` header string is stored as is. With ASCII strings, little / big endian terms are meaningless because these are arrays of single byte values.

Comment: read() always provides the bytes in the order they are stored in the file (R,I,F,F in this case).  The issue is *how the bytes are interpreted*.  When executing on a little-endian machine *and treating those bytes as an integer variable*, the CPU will interpret the first byte as storing the 8 least significant bits of the integer, and the fourth byte as storing the 8 most significant bits of the integer, etc.  A big-endian CPU would interpret them differently.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but you could write `char riff[5]{}; riff[4] = '\0';` as `char riff[5]{0};`.